# Determine if a certain number is greater than a requirement

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table in MYSQL

```
  prices

cost  name
3.10  salt
4.00  soda
1.00  bread
1.50  candy
3.50  bread
4.00  candy
```

and I want to be able to only display the items where ALL the item are over 3.00

so something like

```
cost  name
3.10  salt
4.00  soda
```

would be my result

how can I do this in MYSQL?

Comment: Have you checked a mySQL manual? It should not be too hard.

Comment: I think any MySQL tutorial would cover this within the first 5 minutes.

Comment: @RyanKempt I doubt that. You're misunderstanding the quesiton.

Comment: What about the 3.50 bread and 4.00 candy? Did you not want those to be part of the resultset?

Comment: It's very good that you posted your sample data along with the output you wanted from that data. The only thing missing here is at least an attempt to do this yourself. (Even if it's nowhere close, it's important to at least try something to solve the question yourself before posting here.)

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I see. Haha, you're completely right. Subquery, not a WHERE - maybe day 5, not minute 5. =P

Comment: @DevlshOne: The bread and candy both have rows that are below 3.00 (bread has a 1.00 row, candy has a 1.50); the question asks for rows where **all items are over 3.00**, so bread and candy would be excluded.

Comment: I do have code but its for a different table.  I just made up a quick example to see how it's done then I try it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM prices p1
JOIN (SELECT name, MIN(cost) mincost
      FROM prices
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING mincost > 3) p2
ON p1.name = p2.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a min inside a subquery or a join.

```
select * from prices
  where name in (select name from prices group by name having min(cost) > 3);
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab0e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select cost,name from prices where cost>3.00 order by name;
```

output will be

```
cost  name
3.50  bread
4.00  candy
3.10  salt
4.00  soda
```